# GRPC code 9 failed precondition on time.Time filter query using the Go client

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm getting a `rpc error: code = 9 desc =` (no 'desc' in the error message) using the `cloud.google.com/go/datastore` client package.

I have a struct:

```
type UserWidget struct {
    ID      string    `datastore:"id"`
    UserID  string    `datastore:"user"`
    Widget  string    `datastore:"widget"`
    Updated time.Time `datastore:"updated"`
}
```

And I'm attempting to execute a query against the populated datastore:

```
q := ds.NewQuery(userWidgetEntity)
q = q.Filter("user =", userID)
q = q.Filter("updated >", time.Now().Add(-1*duration))
```

The query executes fine if the updated filter isn't set, but fails with the above error if it is. I also see data in datastore and the updated field is listed as an index. A GQL `update < DATETIME()` query executes correctly as well. I took a look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/blob/master/datastore/query.go#L165 and it doesn't look like it handles synthetic literals. Maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter on multiple properties requires an index to be defined. You should have an index.yaml file that includes:

```
indexes:
  - kind: UserWidget
    properties:
    - name: user
    - name: updated
```

That should be included in the error message; unfortunately there's a [bug](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/132) preventing that from happening.

Comment: Yep, just tried switching to an int field and it didn't work either. Thanks!